# Worth vs Well worth

Tags: word-choice, adverbs, relative-pronouns

I want to say that something is worth it, the subject is mentioned in the previous sentence, so I want to you just write "it", so i won´t repeat the same subject in two consecutive sentences, but generally the meaning I aim for is "it is worth the effort".

My question is which of these forms are acceptable:

- "It is worth it" (I think this is ok)
- "It is well worth it" (I wonder whether this is ok or not, i feel
  like "well worth" needs some object like "it is well worth your
  time")

Comment: You're fine to use either one. Just consider that "well" adds a nice bit of emphasis to the phrase. If you're particularly impressed with something/heartily recommending something, go with "well worth it", otherwise "worth it" will do.

Comment: It's not immediately obvious to me why, but whereas you can substitute *some* other "intensifiers" (e.g. - *"It's **definitely** worth it"*), it's not really idiomatic to say *"It's **very** worth it"*. ***Well worth it*** is something of a "fixed form".

Comment: You might like to post your comments as answers, @JMB/@FumbleFingers. I was going to post on, but you guys summed it up pretty neatly.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I would add that *"It's **very much** worth it"* sounds more idiomatic to me (still somewhat uncommon, though), but it's also not obvious to me why.

Comment: @sgroves: I think *"It's **very much** worth it"* only really works when the context at least *implies* the speaker is refuting someone else's position that something is ***hardly** worth it at all*. But consider, for example, [*"It's very much a matter of luck"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22It%27s+very+much+a+matter+of+luck%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl). You can't possibly get away with just ***very*** there, and plain ***much*** isn't much better. Which suggests that ***very much*** has its own "rules of engagement", as it were.

Answer (score 2):

Both those forms are correct.

What part of speech the word "worth" is a matter for some debate (https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15982/what-is-the-lexical-class-of-the-word-worth-when-used-in-a-sentence-like-is-t), but you can make the case that it's a preposition, and that's why we use *well* with it for emphasis as we do with other prepositions, e.g. "Put the bag well under the seat in front of you", "The plane was well over China when the engine trouble started".

If you just want to say "worth it" without being more specific, you might also consider using *worthwhile*.